# Visual Studio Code adding 'Unexpected character' automatically

Tags: php, macos, visual-studio-code

[image]

When I am trying to save a file, VsCode adding 'Unexpected character' automatically. I removed these character and try to save again, but every time VsCode adding same character in my file. (check attached image.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved after update 'OS X Sierra' to 'High Sierra'